# Goal (event) trigger is not sending network request

Tags: google-analytics

I want to a goal completion on click of a button.

I have this as click event of the button:

`ga('send', 'event', 'Leads', 'click', 'WhatsApp');`

My goal is set up this way:

Goal type: Event

Category - Equals to - Leads

Action - Equals to - click

Label - Equals to - WhatsApp

Value - Greater than - [left this blank]

It's not working. I have checked here:

- Home > Goal Completions
- Real Time > Conversion
- Admin > Goals

Everything says there are 0 conversions.

When I check Dev Tools > Network, there is no network request being performed when I click the button. The method is called for sure, and there is no console error.

What am I doing wrong? Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this instead of ga:

`gtag('event', 'click', {
  'event_category': 'Leads',
  'event_label': 'WhatsApp'
});`